# Understanding how to filter malicious input from a form using PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

currently I am working on an issue in which a user can submit a form even if the characters used are completely random and attach a random email to them as well.

An example of such an issue is presented in the screenshot

[image: An example of such an issue is presented in the screenshot]

The current PHP code the handles submissions is as follows:

```
    if(empty($_POST['First_Name'])  || 
   empty($_POST['Email']))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}

$firstname = $_POST['First_Name']; 
$lastname = $_POST['Last_Name'];
$email_address = $_POST['Email']; 
$company = $_POST['Company']; 

if (!preg_match(
"/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", 
$email_address))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}

if( empty($errors))
{
    $to = $myemail; 
    $email_subject = "Download Form Submission";
    $email_body = "A new white paper registration was received. ".
    " Visitor Details:\n \n First Name: $firstname \n \n Last Name: $lastname \n \n Email: $email_address \n \n Company:  $company" ; 

    $headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";

    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    //redirect to the appropriate page
    header('Location: news-and-resources.php');
} 
?>
```

Which is accompanied by this form HTML:

```
                    <div class="modal-body">
                             <div class="form-group">
                                 <form method="POST" name="downloadform" action="form-handler3.php" onSubmit="MM_validateForm('firstname','','R','lastname','','R','email','','RisEmail','company','','R');return document.MM_returnValue" accept-charset="iso-8859-1"> 
                                   <p>
                                   <label for='firstname'>First Name</label> <br>
                                   <input name="First_Name" type="text" id="firstname" size="30">
                                   </p>
                                   <p>
                                   <label for='lastname'>Last Name</label> <br>
                                   <input name="Last_Name" type="text" id="lastname" size="30">
                                   </p>
                                   <p>
                                   <label for='email'>Email Address</label> <br>
                                   <input name="Email" type="text" id="email" size="30"> <br>
                                   </p>
                                   <p>
                                   <label for='company'>Company</label><br>
                                   <input name="Company" type="text" id="company" size="30"> <br>
                                   </p>

                                   <p style="text-align:center;"><input type="submit" onclick="modal.close();" value="submit"></p>
                                </form>
                             </div> <!--  END OF FORM GROUP -->
                         </div>    <!--  END OF MODAL BODY -->
```

I'm not sure if I need to validate client side before the submission happens or if I should validate after the submission. Either way, I would like to possible gain insight on how to strip random characters and emails from the form. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You definitely need to validate on the server side, but you may choose to also validate on the client side so that you can give feedback quicker.

Comment: Look for `honey pot` technique. It is simple and very usefull against bots. In addition, if you want to make things right, you need to validate against injection attacks.

Comment: The thing is, how do you know what is random, and what is just a really odd name? (For a given value of odd.) I mean, there are ways to validate that the email is at least of a proper format, but for names, I've worked with people from Poland, Russia, Korea, etc. and some names have legitimately odd spelling.

Comment: Mr. Gearman, you are correct sir! Hence my "Rock and a hard place" situation. Maybe I should focus on the email validation perhaps?

Comment: Add a `captcha` that will at least stop the bots even if the morons still sit and play

Comment: There is not much you can do. The tighter you try and control it, the more likely real emails will get rejected

Comment: Well, for email validation, there are a couple things you can do. The first would be to have it be of type email `<input name="Email" type="email" id="email" size="30">`. That forces the input to at least be in a valid format for an email address. The next step depends on the nature of this form. If this is for account creation on a service, you'd send a verification email to that email address so they at least have to take that step to finish the account creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you need to work out a way to strip random characters so much as you might just want to capture non-human form input. There are many methods like captchas, and [google's ReCaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/).

However, a good PHP method that I have seen work and used myself is a honey pot.

Add something like this to the form

```
   <p class="catchThoseBots" id="honey">
      <label>If you're human leave this blank:</label>
      <input name="robotest" type="text" id="robotest" class="robotest" />
    </p>
```

and hide it with CSS

```
.catchThoseBots{display:none}
```

Then in your form validation check for the value

```
$robotest = $_POST['robotest'];
if($robotest){
 //is a robot proceed no further
}else{
 //is a person
}
```

I have done this a few times but the article that I kept around in my notes when I started doing this is [here](http://devgrow.com/simple-php-honey-pot/)

The idea is that robots are just filling in the form with data and hoping to get a submission for whatever goal they are trying to fulfill. With the honey pot their lackadaisical way of doing this gets them no where.